# Exercise involving Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I want to solve the following exercise:

John tells the truth two out of every three times he is asked, while Peter tells the truth four out of every five times. Both agree in assuring that from a box of marbles containing 6 marbles of different colors a red one was taken. Determine the probability that this statement is true.

So, consider:
A:John tells the truth

B:Peter tells the truth

C:A red marble comes out of the marble box.

I think our objective is to determine

$$P(E \mid A \cap B)=\frac{P(A \cap C \mid E) P(E)}{P(A \cap C)}$$

Thinking that $P(A)= \frac{2}{3}$, $P(B)= \frac{4}{5}$

And using the total probability theorem I could determine $P(A \cap C)$

I really don't see clearly how to perform the exercise approach, it is a bit confusing. Any help?

Comment: You are presumably assuming that they tell the truth at random and independently of the other.  Also presumably there are $6$ colours they could have said, and each colour is equally likely.  I would look at $P(R)=\frac16$ as the probability a red ball came out and $P(JR)$ as probability of "John says red" and $P(PR)$ as probability of "Peter says red".  You then get $P(E \mid JR \cap PR) = \frac{P(JR \cap PR \mid E)P(E)}{P(JR \cap PR)} = \frac{P(JR \cap PR \mid E)P(E)}{\sum_c P(JR \cap PR \mid c)P(c)}$ where $c$ represents the six different colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events you should be looking at are:

$J$: John says the marble was red

$P$: Peter says the marble was red

$R$: The marble was red

Then the probability we are trying to calculate is $P(R | J \cap P)$, i.e. the probability the marble is actually red given that John and Peter both say that it was red.

From Bayes' theorem, you can express this as:

$$P(R | J \cap P) = \frac{P(J \cap P | R) P(R)}{P(J \cap P)}$$

$P(R)$ should be fairly simple to calculate, while $P(J \cap P)$ will involve some decomposition into parts of $P(J \cap P \cap R)$ and $P(J \cap P \cap R^c)$.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, it is really useful, but I did not understand well "a decomposition into parts", could you please clarify this idea a little?

Comment: Perhaps to find the probability of the intersection of the three events, it would be good to consider that the probability of the intersection can be written by product of conditionals or just extends my problem?

Comment: Yes, the intersection of the three events needs to be written as a product of conditional. Example:
$$
P(J\cap{P}\cap{R^c})=P(J\cap{P}|R^c)P(R^c)=\frac13\frac15\frac56
$$

Comment: @tps Well, if I follow what you say I think I get $P(R | J \cap P)=\frac{\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}$, but I'm not sure, as the value does not match the answer in the text

Comment: Yes, I did the same as you write, and I got 8/13. What is the answer in the text? Is this an exercise from some text book?